# Dropshadow filter and other settings for background image in blockquote element

Tags: css, dropshadow

I'm looking to create a style rule for every blockquote element that:

a. sets the background image to the sf_speech.png with no tiling and a horizontal and vertical size of 100% to cover the entire block quote and

b. uses the drop-shadow filter to add a drop shadow filter to add a drop shadow around the speech bubble with horizontal and vertical offsets of 5 pixels, a blur of 10 pixels and the color rgb(51, 51, 51)

This is my code so far:

```
blockquote {
background: url(sf_speech.png) 100% 100% no-repeat;
filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 10px rgb(51, 51, 51));
}
```

Can anyone please advise what i'm missing for this?

Thanks a ton

Comment: I am not sure what the end result is supposed to be but if you're trying to put a shadow around the `blockquote` container then you could use `box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px rgb(51, 51, 51, 1);`. If you need to shadow the text you can use `text-shadow`

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't add how the speech bubble such look like, I can't really give any specific technique on how to make it. Because you will probably end up having trouble styling the actual bubble.

But based on your current description, this such do the trick.

```css
blockquote {
  background: url(https://placehold.it/1000x800) 100% 100% no-repeat;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px rgb(51, 51, 51);
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<blockquote>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce nec nisl aliquam, lobortis erat in, posuere massa. Suspendisse commodo nisi id purus dapibus, quis scelerisque lectus auctor. 
</blockquote>
```

Comment: Thanks! the speech bubble is what the sf_speech.png img is . and i'm supposed to add a drop shadow, is that the same as the box-shadow you mentioned?